# Is there a way to tell sed to ignore symlinks?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I have a directory A with a bunch of files with `.xml` extension that I need to run a search-and-replace on. There are a couple of symlinks (also with `.xml` extension) in A that link to certain files in A. I tried running `sed -i 's/search_regexp/replacement_string/' *.xml` but when it hits a symlink it fails with

```
 sed: ck_follow_symlink: couldn't lstat file.xml: No such file or directory
```

A solution would be to loop around the files that I actually want to modify and call sed on each file, but is there a way to tell sed to ignore symlinks? or just follow them and modify the linked file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@piokuc already named the option for following symlinks, here's how you can ignore them with `find` first:

```
find /path/to/dir/ -type f -name "*.xml" ! -type l -exec sed -i 's/search_regexp/replacement_string/' {} \;
```

or, slightly more efficient:

```
find /path/to/dir/ -type f -name "*.xml" ! -type l | xargs sed -i 's/search_regexp/replacement_string/'
```

The `! -type l` part means "not anything that is a symlink"

Comment: Are symlinks considered as "regular files" (that come under `-type f`)? I ran the find command with `-type f` (without `! -type l`) and it filtered out the symlinks. I'm wondering if `! -type l` is actually needed.

Comment: @fo_x86 that was my suspicion too (that you only need `-type f`) but I thought it was better to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option for that (`man sed`):

```
       --follow-symlinks

          follow symlinks when processing in place
```

The version of sed I'm using is 4.1.5:

```
ariadne{/tmp}:310 --> sed --help | grep follow
  --follow-symlinks
                 follow symlinks when processing in place
ariadne{/tmp}:311 --> sed --version           
GNU sed version 4.1.5
Copyright (C) 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
to the extent permitted by law.
ariadne{/tmp}:312 --> uname -a
Linux ariadne 2.6.34.10-0.6-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT 2011-12-13 18:27:38 +0100 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ariadne{/tmp}:313 -->
```

Comment: Is this option new in sed 4.2? I'm using 4.1.5 (I'd love to update, but my company's systems admin refuses to). I read about this option elsewhere but I don't see it in the man pages.

Comment: I've got 4.1.5 and the option is there

Comment: @fo_x86 Don't know, perhaps the build was configured without the option? I added info on my `sed` version to my answer.